# merge Pandas dataframe with different columns and shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I have two dataframes with Pandas python which i am trying to join / merge/ concat/ ..

[image: df1 with repeating urls in col1 and domain names in col2 , other columns contain information to be preserved]

[image: df2 which contains only unique domains from df1 and some extra information in col3 col4]

I am trying all combinations of merge / join or concat to get all information in df2 - col3, col4 against respective domains in df1 ( which has repeating urls and domains in columns)

desired result :
[image: everytime the domain is matched, relevant information in col3, col4 is matched in resultant df]

I am not sure if any map() with dictionary or any join merge or any function that can help me in this case.
If someone has any clue, please help, I have already tried multiple stackoverflow articles on pandas df merge and join but does not helps.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how='left' on = ['domain'])` what do you get if you merge like this

Comment: @Equinox yes worked. Thanks allot.
I noticed I was having problem in dataframe on particular column and hence was not matching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't understand if "domain" is a simple column or the index of df2.
If it is a column:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, how="left", on="domain")
```

If "domain" is the index:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, how="left", left_index=True, right_on="domain")
```

I hope this is useful. Let me know if it solves your question